# Token ring protocol Efficiency and Cycle time?

Tags: networking, formula, concept, network-efficiency

I read **Token ring protocol** from a book Forouzon.

According to book,

Let **N** be the number of stations in the ring, **THT** the token holding time, **Tt** be the transmission time of packet, **Tp** be the propagation time of packet on Channel/ Link.

Then **Cycle Time = n * THT + Tp** (this is cycle time for token)

and **efficiency = (useful time)/(Cycle Time)**

Here useful time is stated as **N * Tt**. (justified as transmission time at each station in single cycle of token passing)

And thus proven **efficiency = (N * Tt)/(n*THT + Tp**)

My question is: **why not this (N*Tt) is added in Cycle time?**

so the efficiency could become **efficiency = (N * Tt)/(n*THT + Tp +N * Tt**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But it has **already** been included.

Token Holding time is **THT** = **Transmission Time + Ring Latency time** (for single round of packet transmission)

As **(THT = Tt + Tp)** .

Comment: Yes it got cleared as it was a later part of explanation which i read.